# Tengo un problema en el siguiente código

Tags: c++, visual-studio

La idea es poder escribir 15 palabras no más de 20 letras cada una y una letra y que luego las 15 palabras empiecen desde la letra que he escrito por ejempl:
palabra = cuaderno
Letra = a
Final = aderno
El problema con el código es que no me dijita el final y se cierra automáticamente.
El codigo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#define n 20
#define m 15

int main()
{
    char palabra[m][n],letra;
    int i,k,largo,j;
//cargo la matriz de palabras
    for(k=0; k<m; k++)
    {
             printf("Ingrese una palabra: ");
             gets(palabra[k]);
    }
    //Ingresan la letra
    printf("Ingrese una letra: ");
    scanf("%c", &letra);
    for(k=0; k<m; k++)
    {
             printf("%s\n\n", palabra[k]);
    }

    //terminar el ejercicio
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Podrias mostrar que hiciste hasta ahora, y donde tenes problemas? los ejercicios no suelen resolverse en la pagina, pero si te podemos ayudar si estas trabado en algun lado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> La idea es poder escribir 15 palabras no más de 20 letras cada una

Ya empezamos mal. Para que que cada palabra pueda tener hasta 20 letras es necesario que el buffer pueda almacenar, al menos, 21 caracteres... no hay que olvidar el caracter nulo que finaliza las cadenas. Así esta línea:

```
#define n 20
```

debería quedar así:

```
#define n 21
```

Aunque quedaría más *rollo C++* si en vez de `#define` usases `const int`:

```
const int N = 21;
```

Lo de nombrar las constantes (o macros) en mayúsculas es una convención prácticamente universal que sirve para poder entender mejor el código.

Por otro lado dices de leer palabras... entonces `gets` no es tu mejor aliado ya que `gets` no se detiene hasta encontrar un salto de línea o el final del buffer de entrada... lo normal en estos casos es usar `scanf`:

```
scanf("%s",palabra[k]);
```

Aunque ya que estamos en C++ lo lógico será usar `std::string`, aunque no lo voy a usar por si se da la casualidad de que tienes vetado su uso (yo me cuestiono eso de enseñar C++ sin permitir que la gente use C++).

> El problema con el código es que no me dijita el final y se cierra automáticamente.

Si no le pones una parada al programa, cuando finalice es posible que la consola se cierre sola (si lo estás ejecutando desde un IDE sobretodo si es antiguo, tipo Dev-C++). Como te digo, para evitar que el programa se cierre solo lo mejor es esperar a que el usuario presione una tecla. Como dices que usas *VS* puedes usar `system("PAUSE")`. No es la solución más recomendada pero en Windows funciona:

```
//terminar el ejercicio
system("PAUSE")
return 0;
```

Ahora bien, tu programa no localiza dónde se encuentra la letra en cada palabra, y entiendo que eres consciente de ello. Te sugiero intentar resolver esa parte antes de que alguien te la de hecha... se aprende más.

Comment: hola, tome los consejos que me diste y funciono pero me falta una parte me podrías ayudar?

Comment: @Gastonggp por favor, borra tu respuesta, pues no es tal cosa, y crea una pregunta nueva. Si una respuesta soluciona los problemas planteados en la pregunta no olvides marcarla como solución y, si la respuesta tiene la calidad suficiente, vota positivo. Solo puede haber una respuesta como solución pero puedes votar a todas las que consideres oportuno.